# How to call converter again when data source is getting initialized to populate items on View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, converters

I am using `converter` to assign price values in `View`. I have a model `ItemList` in `converter` which is **initializing after the screen load finish**.

That's why data is not populating. I want to call converter again when `ItemList` getting values. How can I do it either from code behind or MVVM. I am using MVVM pattern.

This is my code

```
<Label
FontFamily="{StaticResource mediumFontFamily}"
FontSize="Small"
Margin="0,0,0,9"
HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
TextColor="{x:Static local:Theme.BodyHeaderTextColor}"
IsVisible="True"
Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}}" />
```

Converter file

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    
    if (value == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else if (value isItemModel itemModel)
    {
        decimal price = 0;

        var ItemList = IoC.Get<Service>().ItemList;
        if (isLevel)
        {
            var modifiersPrice = itemModel.ProductValue;
            if (modifiersPrice!=null) 
            {
                price = modifiersPrice;
            }
        }
        return Helper.Region(currency, $"{price:0.00}");
    }
    else
    {
      return Helper.Region(currency, itemModel.Price);
    }
}
```

Please ignore mistake in converter code as I have modified it. Just I need to know when `IoC.Get<Service>().ItemList` gets value in viewmodel, how can I hit converter again so that my UI will have data.

Comment: What is your `Label` actually binding to? If you bind it so something actually relating to `ItemList` then the act of setting a value on it should trigger the binding/converter update so long as you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Bijington - There is an existing Labels in the layout those are binding using same thing converter and generating list. So they are not using INotifyPropertyChanged. Same way I want to do it.

Comment: `IoC.Get<Service>().ItemList` should call in viewmodel , and the viewmodel should implemnet `INotifyPropertyChanged ` .

Comment: @R15 thanks, would you be able to share some more XAML? Basically I am assuming you have a `ListView/CollectionView` which the `Label` will be held inside?